# What's the most efficient method to overlay data on top of a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I need to created hundreds of PDFs each day.  Each PDF will be the same blank purchase order, on top of which will be pasted various data points such as offer prices, dates, buyer names, seller names, etc.  This will have the effect of creating hundreds of purchase orders each day, automatically.

I am thinking the best way to do this would be to take the data and paste it on top of the PDF using x/y coordinates.

I am looking for this community's thoughts on which technology would be best to use to put the data on top of / in the PDF.  What are your thoughts?  What questions can I answer for you that might give you further clarification?

I'm new to this forum, so apologies in advance if I'm posting this in the wrong place.  If you have suggestions about where I should post this or what tags I should add, I would appreciate that as well!

Comment: An alternative would be to prepare your blank order with AcroForm fields and for each order fil in the form. Other than that it is difficult to give input as you don't mention your development context (programming language and runtime environment; pdf library of choice).

Comment: Are you already doing this, or is this for a new project? If existing, what are the issues? Do you already have the (pdf) template designed?

Comment: This is a new project.  I have a PDF that somebody else created.  It's a purchase contract.  I need to copy different dates, prices, names into this same PDF, over and over again, automatically and quickly, each day.  I think there are lots of ways to do this, but was hoping somebody had insight on the "Best" way to get it done...